# Usage of Lagrange Multipliers in multivariable calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, vector-analysis, lagrange-multiplier

I just learnt about Lagrange Multipliers & am confused about why they are useful. Why can we not just check for critical points by checking if the gradient vector of the objective function $f$ is $0$? Is it because for higher dimensions the boundary of a set may be infinite unlike the case when we have $[a,b]$ so if there is no critical point within $(a,b)$, the max and min lie at the endpoints.

Also, I may be wrong but the general procedure is to first check for critical points of $g$, the constraint function, on the level set and then look for Lagrange points. If this is correct, could someone explain why we look for critical points of $g$ instead of $f$? It doesn't make sense to look for maximum or minimum points of the constraint function..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it would help to consider a simple example:

> Maximize/minimize the function $f(x,y) = 3x + 4y$ subject to the constraint $g(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 = 25$

We can now address one of your concerns: *why can we not just check for critical points by checking if the gradient vector of the objective function $f$ is $0$?* As you can see, the gradient of the objective function is $\nabla f = (3,4)$, which is never zero.  By your logic, we should expect no extrema since we have no critical points (you can verify, however, that we obtain a max at $(3,4)$ and a min at $(-3,-4)$).

To your second question: it amounts to the fact that points where the gradient of $g$ is zero or undefined are "poorly behaved" points over the domain on which we're optimizing.  For instance, consider the example:

> Maximize/minimize the function $f(x,y) = y$ subject to the constraint $g(x,y) = x^2 - y^3 = 0$

Verify that, although there are no Lagrange points, $f$ attains a minimum at $(x,y) = (0,0)$.  To see what I mean by "poorly behaved", note that $x^2 - y^3 = 0$ traces out the graph of $y = x^{2/3}$, which fails to be differentiable at $x = 0$.

Comment: I don't understand your second point. I can't see how your example shows why we look for critical points of the constraint function instead of the objective function. 

For my first question, could you explain what exactly goes wrong? Goes wrong as in why the following argument fails : A differentiable function has derivative 0 at every critical point, and a global extremum is a local extremum (critical point) if it is in the interior.

Comment: @Saad as I said for the second problem: there are no Lagrange points.  There are also no critical points for the objective function, which has gradient $(0,1)$.  So, if we want to find the max/min, we have to look at something else.  As it turns out, the critical points of $g$ are what we would have missed.

Comment: @Saad as for your argument: I really don't see how it's supposed to apply to the first problem at all.  Yes, $f$ has a derivative $0$ at every critical points... but in this problem the derivative of $f$ is never $0$ (or undefined).  Also, what do you mean by the "interior" in the context of this problem?

Comment: Essentially, if we have a real valued function $f$ on a closed interval $[a,b]$ and it is differentiable on $(a,b)$, then finding global extremums is easy. We just find the critical points of $f$ along with what values $f$ takes on the boundary (in this case $f(a)$ and $f(b)$), and then compare them. Why does this approach not generalize to finding global extreme points in higher dimensions? We find all of the critical points of the objective function which satisfy the constraint, and then we find all values in the boundary as these are the only other places of global extremas

Comment: By interior, I mean the largest open set which satisfies $g(x,y) = 25$. Also, could you explain why we "miss" the critical points of $g$? Is it ever possible that we miss the critical points of $f$?

Comment: @Saad All I meant by "missing the critical points" is that if we were just to take the naive approach of checking the critical points of $f$ and the Lagrange points, then we wouldn't find a minimum.

Comment: @Saad here's a way to think of it, for the case of a non-empty interior (e.g. if the first problem were $g(x,y) \leq 25$).  To begin, we look for critical points of the objective function on the $2$-dimensional interior.  Then, we consider the problem of maximizing $f$ on the $1$-dimensional boundary which, as you observed, contains infinitely many points.  Compare this to the $1$-dimensional problem where, after looking at the interior, we maximize the objective function on the $0$-dimensional boundary, i.e. the points $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I understand that we have missed those critical points so we generally need to consider them separately, but why is it that we miss those critical points in the first place? The statement of the theorem I did was that either $a$ is a critical point for $f$, the objective function, or $a$ is a Lagrange point, and the case seems to be neither here so there must be something wrong with the statement

Comment: @Saad either your theorem has a more flexible definition of a Lagrange point than I’m used to, or your theorem assumes that the gradient of the constraint function is never zero or undefined over the domain in question.

Comment: I see. Could you provide a link to the correct statement then? Thank you for the discussion so far, but I don't think I can ask you to prove the theorem in a comment :)